# Gradient colour in backgroundColor JS

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I am trying to change the background colour in the code below into gradient but not sure on how to approach this:

```
bandwidthChart = new Chart($("#bandwidthChart"), {
                    type: "bar",
                    data: {
                        labels: response.extra.labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "{% trans "Bandwidth" %}",
                            backgroundColor: "rgb(11, 98, 164)",
                            data: response.extra.data
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: response.extra.postUnits,
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    }
                });
```

This is what I have:

backgroundColor: "**rgb(11, 98, 164)**"

I would like to change this colour into a linear gradient from top to bottom. Any help appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: What is `Chart`?

Comment: Sorry did not explain clearly what its for. I am using charts on my website to display the information (linear, pie charts etc.). I would like to make them look a bit fresher with gradient background rather than single colour.

Comment: It depends highly on your specific implementation of the Chart class. Without that it's impossible to tell why ~Srikanth495's answer below wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Check Chartjs' documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html?h=backgroundcolor in order to know what you can pass to `backgroundColor`.

Comment: @Squareoot Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a snippet using **Chart.js 2.7.1:**

```
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bandwidthChart').getContext('2d');
var purple_orange_gradient = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0, 'orange');
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(1, 'purple');

bandwidthChart = new Chart(, {
                    type: "bar",
                    data: {
                        labels: response.extra.labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "{% trans "Bandwidth" %}",
                            backgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient,
                            data: response.extra.data
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: response.extra.postUnits,
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    }
```

Demo : https://codepen.io/jonathandion/pen/aEpVba

Comment: That's it! Thanks Jonathan. Works like charm. Only thing is when you hover the mouse over the chart it doesn't display the overlay (darker) colour over the gradient, just removes gradient from underneath. Thanks.

Comment: Just add `hoverBackgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient` or any color you want.

Comment: Thank you once again Jonathan. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

you can try it as:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red , yellow);
```

This would tell the system to change from red to yellow as it moves to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, although that's what I tried thinking it will work but it doesn't in this case.